# Нужно ли закрывать потоки ввода/вывода в конце программы?

Tags: потоки-данных, io, filestream, java-stream, fstream

Иногда в чьём-то коде (совершенно небольших программ, например, решений олимпиадных задач) можно встретить как в самом конце закрываются потоки I/O. Например, на *Java*:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
...
in.close();
```

Или на *Python*:

```
in = open("input.txt", "r")
...
in.close()
```

Насколько это важный момент? Мне кажется, что он вовсе не нужен, т.к. при завершении программы и так все потоки закроются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правы в том, что при завершении программы потоки будут закрыты операционной системой. Однако, есть правила "хорошего тона" в программировании, которые требуют закрывать ресурс как только необходимость в нём отпала.

Вот практический пример, почему это "хороший стиль". Вы пишете некую программу и не закрываете ресурсы, понадеявшись на ОС. Но затем Ваш код из самостоятельной единицы превращается в часть кода другой, более мощной программы. Но Ваш код не освобождает ресурсы и в результате эти ресурсы "висят" невостребованными. Более того, Ваш код выполняется много раз и каждый раз открывает ресурс и не закрывает его. Такое поведение по меньшей мере приводит к напрасному расходу этих ресурсов, а в более глобальной перспективе замедляет работу не только программы, но и компьютера, на котором она выполняется.

Я думаю, что ресурсы закрывать нужно всегда. Это хороший тон. Но если Вам лень и весь код программы помещается на один экран, то можно обойтись и без этого.

---

Кстати, в указанных в вопросе языках существуют конструкции, автоматически закрывающие ресурсы. Вот как будет выглядеть приведённый в вопросе код.

*Java*:

```
try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // ...
}
```

*Python*:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as in:
    // ...
```

Comment: Надо бы еще упомянуть тот факт, что поток при закрытии может зелать что-нибудь нетривиальное, чего ОС делать за него не умеет.
  Если при дальнейшем развитии программы простой I/O поток заменить на нечто более хитрое - при выходе будет сюрприз.